# htaccess to redirect submain with sub-pages on another server

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect my sub-domain http://listings.mywebsite.com/i/ to "mywebsite.com" but the trouble is, this "/i/" and all of the pages following this "/i" are hosted on another server.  I created a redirect to direct "listings.mywebsite.com/" to my home page, so no problem there...  But this "/i/" at the end is giving my trouble.

I tried several htaccess redirect scripts found within this site but none of them worked, likely because this /i/ are not on my server.

That is, if I go to "listings.mywebsite.com/i/" , I see a "document unreachable" error page because this "/i" somehow is connected to this company's server.  However, if I go to http://listings.mywebsite.com , I'm redirected to my homepage.

I asked the company to remove me from their servers, but they are not doing it yet and are being slow if no response at all (something about keeping me active in their servers in case I decide to come back to them but I'm not.

Thanks much for any help!

Frank

Comment: So you want to redirect `listings.mywebsite.com/i/` to `mywebsite.com/`?

Comment: In a word, yes.  But this /i/ folder and everything that follows it is on another server.  I have listings.mywebsite.com/ hosted on my server but listings.mywebsite.com/i/17644/ and any other page are somehow another server. It's as if this /i/ directory is holding the listings.mywebsite.com hostage.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file on `listings.mywebsite.com` host:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^listings\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^i/(.+)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: I wish this worked, but it doesn't. I apologize if posting the URL is wrong, but look here: listings.mynewportnewsrealestate.com/i/  I have listings.website.com without the "/i/" redirecting to my home page but when the /i/ is added, it's a different page that's actually hosted on another server not mine. I made sure the CNAME that was attached to this /i/ was deleted.

Comment: Posting URL is fine for explaining your problem. I am unable to understand what exactly isn't working for you.